# Best way to support multiple forms in mvc3 with validation annotiation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, partial-views

In an mvc3 project I want to have 2 forms on one page. One form is to register a user and the other one is to logon.

There are two submit buttons. One to register, one to logon.

In the model there are validation annotiation e.g. username is required, passwords must match and so on.

The problem is, that the validation annotiation affect each other. So that when the register button is pressed, the validation for the logon username is invalid.

I have tried to write partial views, or to do everything in one view an write some custom annotiations, respecting the pressed button.

But that all seems to wrong. That can not be the best solution.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I approach this problem; where you need 2 or more ViewModels binding to your view, is to create a encompasing ViewModel with 2 properties, then assign the individual *login* and *register* models to each property. e.g. (minus any validation you wish to add)

```
public class LogOnViewModel {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterViewModel {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class WelcomeScreenViewModel {
    public LogOnViewModel LogOnModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterViewModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

In my **Welcome** view I would have `@model namespace.WelcomeScreenViewModel` at the top together with 2 partial views pointing to _LogOn and _Register like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOn", Model.LogOnModel)
@Html.Partial("_Register", Model.RegisterModel)
```

That way your partial views are passed the correct models and are also re-usable as partial view else where in your web app.

Comment: When I do it like this, the fields like Username, Passowrd and so on are always null.

Comment: When posting your data? Have you got the form in each of your partial views pointing to the correct actions on your controllers? e.g. `Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account")`

Comment: My HttpPost function looks like this: `public ActionResult Index(WelcomeScreenModel welcomeScreenModel)`. Here the values are Null. If I change it to `public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)`, then there are two values, one for password and one for username. Is there a way to use the WelcomeScreenModel?

Comment: You should have your `@Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account")` code in each of your partial views, each form will then post data to separate actions on your controller that handle those specific ViewModels. e.g. `[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult LogOn (LogOnViewModel model) {}` - You should try not post data back and forth that is not required or you run the risk of this happening...http://freshbrewedcode.com/joshbush/2012/03/05/mass-assignment-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: In short use `WelcomeScreenViewModel` to put the data on the screen and separate (more specific) Actions and ViewModels to post the data back to your controllers.

Comment: Ok that works, the only thing, that I think I cannot achieve is, that I want to come back to the welcome screen, with the error message on error. Because I have to do a redirect to come back to the welcome screen from the logon or register function, but thats ok.

Comment: I suppose you could overload your Index method with one that accepts a `WelcomeScreenViewModel`. Then in your LogOn action build a new WelcomeScreenViewModel object adding the LogOn model you already have to it and `return Index(welcomeModel);`