# Partial View validation with composite view model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model

I have a screen with two forms.  One allows login to the site, the other allows login to an ftp.

The Login view is strongly typed with WelcomeScreenViewModel (combined models).
Each form is a strongly typed partial view.

Here are the class definitions.

```
public class LogOnViewModel
    {
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("username", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("password", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class FTPViewModel
    {
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("username", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("password", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class WelcomeScreenViewModel
    {
        public LogOnViewModel LogOnModel { get; set; }
        public FTPViewModel FTPModel { get; set; }
    }
```

My main page inherits WelcomeScreenViewModel and I render my partial views like this:

Html.RenderPartial("Logon", Model.LogOnModel);

Html.RenderPartial("FTP", Model.FTPModel);

My Controller code:

```
// To display blank login on load of page
public ActionResult Login(string language)
        {
            WelcomeScreenViewModel combined = new WelcomeScreenViewModel();
            combined.FTPModel = new FTPViewModel();
            combined.LogOnModel = new LogOnViewModel();
            return View(combined);
        }

// Called when clicking submit on first form
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Logon(string language, LogOnViewModel logon)
        {
            WelcomeScreenViewModel combined = new WelcomeScreenViewModel();
            combined.FTPModel = new FTPViewModel();
            combined.LogOnModel = logon;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewData["result"] = "Invalid login info / Informations de connexion incorrectes";

                // This is the part I can't figure out.  How do I return page with validation summary errors
                return View(logon);
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }            
        }
```

So far, my problem is with what to return when my ModelState is invalid. How do I return page with validation summary errors? The code displayed above just returns the partial view form (not inside the master) with no validation.  What am I doing wrong?  I got started with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682316/best-way-to-support-multiple-forms-in-mvc3-with-validation-annotiation), but it didn't show enough code to help me.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 problems with my code.

1) The two sub models must have different names for each field.

```
public class LogOnViewModel
    {
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("username", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("password", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class FTPViewModel
    {
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("username", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string ftpUserName { get; set; }
        [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("password", typeof(MyLabels.labels))]
        [Required]
        public string ftpPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

2) This is the code to use to return the validation and values:

```
return View("~/Views/Login/Login.aspx",combined);
```